# Android WebView New Window URL

Tags: android, webview

I've got an issue with Android `WebView`, I want to open a URL with `target='_blank'` in the same `WebView`, just as all other `URLs` are opening.

Also note that im overriding this method of `WebViewClient` **'shouldOverrideUrlLoading**', for handling URL redirects (so that all URL redirects are opened in my `WebView`) but in case of URLs with `target='_blank'` this method doesn't get fired.

Kindly help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're you ever able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I recently opened one URL having target="_blank" in the same webView. What was happening in your case?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add :

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
```

And in shouldOverride :

```
view.loadUrl(url);
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

//Enable support multiple windows
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override 
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message resultMsg)
    {
        //return true or false after performing the URL request
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `WebChromeClient` and handling `onCreateWindow()`.