# Link should be open in same web view in Android

Tags: android

I am new in Android and I am trying to open a Link in webview using this code

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webinfo);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://oslobokfestival.netteam.no/artical.php?articalid=93");
    myWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lbg);
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

and in this HTML page contains some links and I want that when user click that link should be open in same webview,
at this point its opening in mobile browser, please give me appropriate solution..
Thanks.

Comment: You can check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843029/android-webview-new-window-url) which is the same as what you want to do.

Comment: you can get URL when click on URL >>>>

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You need to add [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your WebView in order to open it in the WebView. Something like

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this works, but is there a way to allow links that have target=_blank applied on them to be opened in new window??

Comment: Its working fine but I want to add an icon on external webview

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is deprecated and we can use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` instead.

Comment: getUrl() requires API level 21, So you couldn't run app on some devices.

Comment: The documentation says you should not call `view.loadUrl(...)` and instead just return false: "Note: Do not call WebView#loadUrl(String) with the request's URL and then return true. This unnecessarily cancels the current load and starts a new load with the same URL. The correct way to continue loading a given URL is to simply return false, without calling WebView#loadUrl(String)." (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))

Answer (score 14):

Try remove @Overrideand an put it after loadurl
This work for me...

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://someurl.com");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
        viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Overrideand is just annotation to tell your overriding a method, you can (and you should) keep it in there

Answer (score 5):

For me its works by simply overriding

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` methods and

return `super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)`

that will handle all links in same `WebView`.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
         return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the method **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** of [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) like this:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.toString());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and add this tag `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your **manifest file** To get access to the internet

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("#");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice but put some explanation to make answer more respective !

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it kotlin and also take care of the Versions below 21:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView,
                    request: WebResourceRequest
                ): Boolean {
                    view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
                    return false
                }
            }
        } else {
            myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                    view?.loadUrl(url.toString())
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
```