# URL intents on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to know if the following is possible.

We are tracking downloads of apps (installs). Our users have to click on a URL which opens a browser to our http tracking link. This then redirects to Google Play for the user to download the app. The user is presented with an option asking whether they want to continue in Play App or go to the Play website.

This is the URL:
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.proptiger

Is it possible to force the URL to open in the App using the following: market://details?id=com.proptiger - I cannot get this to work in a browser.

Can anyone confirm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that market://details?id=com.proptiger does work as redirect in the android browser but it doesn't work if you type it directly into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

[Android WebView click open within WebView not a default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986788/android-webview-click-open-within-webview-not-a-default-browser)

The url can be opened in App , Fot that 3 points to be remmebered

1. create webview in xml
2. create own webviewclient and
3. set webviewclient

you can refer this url
[Android WebView click open within WebView not a default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986788/android-webview-click-open-within-webview-not-a-default-browser)

Comment: Sorry I've probably not made myself clear. I am clicking a URL which I want to open in the browser: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.proptiger But I want to force it to open in the Google Play App instead of giving the user a choice. Is this possible at all?