# Problems in webview component (java Android)

Tags: java, android, webview

Problems in webview component (java Android).

I created a screen to receive payments:

```
public class PaymentOnLineFragment extends Fragment {
}
```

This screen has only one component webview:

```
View v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.activity_pagamento, null);
```

xml with the layout has content:

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android: orientation = "horizontal"    android: layout_width = "fill_parent"    android: layout_height = "fill_parent">  <WebView android: id = "@ + id / webview"      android: layout_width = "fill_parent"      android: layout_height = "fill_parent" />
```

I carry my php page in webview:

```
webView.loadUrl("my_payment_link.php");
```

My problem is:

I need to update every 5 seconds my php page, so I did put in the  of the page:

```
 "onload="setTimeout ('delayer ()', 5000)" na tag body
```

The page opens normally in webview the first time, but when pass the 5 seconds is the refresh, the link is opened in the default android browser (another window opens) and the webview is not updated.

I want the page to be updated within the webview own (ie in my own application).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView click open within WebView not a default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986788/android-webview-click-open-within-webview-not-a-default-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reload the page from your android code instead of using javascript?
you could do it with a thread or a handler, and call `mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.websitehere.php");` 
every n seconds!

Comment: you say for me to create a thread that runs every 5 seconds and do the reload?

Comment: I think that would be slow.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what is your reasoning for saying it would be slower than doing it with javascript?

Comment: @user2725921yes... or, you could use a handler, and with the method postMessageDelayed() you can reload the webview.

Comment: I don't really trust WebViews ever since I worked on a hybrid app, that's all. He essentially needs to define the WebViewClient's shouldOverrideUrlLoading.