# Android Webview - Dynamically added href opens link in app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

My android app has a webview, All links are opened on chrome when being clicked. However, when a link is created dynamically, somehow it opens inside webview. I am adding href url dynamically using;

Html

```
<a id="downloadpic" href="">Click</a>
```

jQuery

```
var myurl = "http://www.example.org";
$("#downloadpic").attr("href",myurl);
```

Which way should I follow to make it open on browser ?

Comment: You could try adding `target="_blank"` which is usually how it is done in the browser

Comment: Same problem happens.

Comment: Maybe you need to update the target dynamically too?

Comment: Have a look at this answer, there appears to be an option to declare a handler and then return false or true to govern how the link is opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986788/android-webview-click-open-within-webview-not-a-default-browser

Comment: Hi Mikkel, yes I am already using shouldOverrideUrlLoading() on my app. But It doesnt work on dynamically added ones. Maybe its a bug.