# android webview stay in app

Tags: java, android, webview, android-widget

I have a webview in my android app, but when someone navigates around the site, it opens in a new window, i want it to stay inside the webview.. is there a way to do this easily? Here is the code in my activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shop);
    WebView webview;
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link should be open in same web view in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link should be open in same web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You'll have to create a `WebViewClient`:

```
public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then set it to your `WebView` like this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
```

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is deprecated on Android N. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484074/is-shouldoverrideurlloading-really-deprecated-what-can-i-use-instead

Answer (score 33):

Or you can just do that, without creating a new class:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

It works for me.

Comment: Not Working. Nothing happening when clicking on that button

Answer (score 1):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

If you want to customize then you should override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)`. but it's deprecated in API 24. You can use `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view,WebResourceRequest request)`. actually both of them needs to return false.

[Android WebView Example](https://androidride.com/android-webview-example-tutorial-kotlin-java-download-source-code/)