# Why am I getting "WebPage not available" when running my web app?

Tags: android

Why is it happening?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity

    {

    WebView browser;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

        browser.loadUrl("www.microsoft.com");
    }
}
```

But when I run the Android HTML5 app I get this screen  goo.gl/uDkj1

I also tried other possibilities such as http:// in front or end the address with a slash and so on.

Comment: maybe using url without http:// doesn't cause any error but always use http:// for your works. This is better way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you forgot to set the internet permission:

```
<manifest [...]>
 [...]
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you, now it is opening the address in a browser instead of opening the page within the app itself.  Why is that?

Comment: You need a WebViewClient to prevent that. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13542994/1333975) out.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the Internet permission set in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Edit:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {         
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, now it is opening the address in a browser instead of opening the page within the app itself.  Why is that?

Comment: You'll need to set a WebViewClient, I've amended my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

as the other answer said you must include the `Internet` permission, but please note that 
`http://www.google.com` differ of `www.google.com` so please include the protocol you are using in the `URL`.