# Android webview navigate in app not open browser

Tags: android, browser, webview

In my app I have a tab and a webview in, but when I clic on a link, 
the browser it's open.

I want to stay in my app, I have read this answer: [android webview stay in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542982/android-webview-stay-in-app)

But I can't do it. I don't know what exactly I must do .

Here is my EventsFragments.java :

```
public class EventsFragment extends Fragment 

{
     WebView myWebView;
     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabone, container, false);
                WebView myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.fr");
        return view;
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is not clear in the correct answer in [android webview stay in app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542982/android-webview-stay-in-app)?

Comment: > You'll have to create a WebViewClient > New Class ? And then set it to your WebView like this:      webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());    in EventsFragments.java ? but where

Comment: `New Class ?`

Yes.

`in EventsFragments.java ? but where` 

Usually after inflating the `WebView`, so after

    `WebView myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);`

in your code.

Comment: It's work ! Thanks for precisions :)