# open links in an in-app WebView

Tags: android, webview, inappbrowser

I want to implement an in app browser so that all links in my app will open in the in-app browser ( same as Facebook app handle links).

I have created new activity that takes a Url and open it , but i don't how to initiate it when a link inside a TextView is clicked (I have also spannable text inside the textView that handles Hashtagging).

thanks.

Comment: I have made an app which opens a link. You can find the code here : https://github.com/akritikts/BioYantra/blob/master/app/src/main/java/in/silive/bioyantra/MainActivity.java

Comment: check this:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542982/android-webview-stay-in-app

Comment: thanks, but i want that all links will open in a separate activity, and i don't have WebView in the MainActivity that is why it is not clear how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library.
This library does what you intend to do.

https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android