# Changing theme to theme.noTitleBar in android

Tags: android, layout, themes, smartphone

I can change the Theme for the app i am doing not to have the title bar. Although this updates the layout i am working on under eclipse adt when i run it in the device the title bar is still there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna hide the titlebar in your activity use the following code `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`
before the `setContentView();`

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the title bar from any one of 3 different places.

1- In a style definition:

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

2- In a manifest file, at the application level, ...

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

...or at the activity level:

```
// either
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
// or (not both)
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

3- In the Activity's Java file, within the onCreate method, just before the call to `setContentView`:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

JGarrido provides a great answer. Here is an extra information if it still does not work for you:

If your emulator says: "Unfortunately [your appname] has stopped." and you find the error message in Android Studio 1.0 RC4:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xyz.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Then open MainActivity.java and change

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

I [found this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/1066234) after struggling for one hour. And hope it can help other developers as well.

PS: And if the links open in a new window afterwards, instead of the same webview window, add [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7309017/1066234) inside the onCreate, in the end.