# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Android Studio 0.4.5

Android documentation for creating custom dialog boxes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

If you want a custom dialog, you can instead display an Activity as a dialog instead of using the Dialog APIs. Simply create an activity and set its theme to Theme.Holo.Dialog in 
the `<activity>` manifest element:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
```

However, when I tried this I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

I am supporting the following, and I can't using something greater than 10 for the min:

```
minSdkVersion 10
targetSdkVersion 19
```

In my styles I have the following:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

And in my manifest I have this for the activity:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
            android:name="com.ssd.register.Dialog_update"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog_update" >
        </activity>
```

Creating the dialog box like this was something I was hopping to do, as I have already completed the layout.

Can anyone tell me how I can get around this problem?

Comment: Are you using `AppCompat` from the support library?

Comment: @Raghunandan, I am new to this but looking at my styles I have the following: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> And I have the following imports: import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; But not sure what all this means.

Comment: You are using `AppCompat` which is form the support library to support actionbars below api level 11. Just use `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >` for the activity in manifest

Comment: @ant2009, to claify what @Raghunandan said: in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, the theme you are specifying for your activity is overriding the theme you are specifying for your application. Remove the `android:theme` line from the `<activity>` tag.

Comment: @ant2009 you want a full screen dialog?

Comment: Doing this will remove the error but not get him to where he wants to be which is an activity with a dialog theme. The general rule is that if you want your activity to have an action bar it should have the AppCompat theme and the java code should extend ActionBarActivity. If you have an activity that doesn't need an action bar (like a dialog themed activity) you can apply any theme to it but the java code must extend plain old activity.

Comment: I have come up with same error and solved this by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797134/how-to-use-and-style-new-alertdialog-from-appcompat-22-1-and-above

Comment: I think the only problem in this case is the context you provide for Dialog constractor. See my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51574281/232727

Comment: If this error comes when you are using FragmentScenario to test your fragment using Espresso, then you can explicity pass R.style.Theme_AppCompat in the fragment scenario's launch method.

Comment: Sometimes it's a cache issue. So just use gradle clean command.

Answer (score 1225, accepted):

The reason you are having this problem is because the activity you are trying to apply the dialog theme to is extending `ActionBarActivity` which requires the `AppCompat` theme to be applied.

**Update**: Extending  `AppCompatActivity` would also  have this problem

In this case, change the Java inheritance from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` and leave the dialog theme in the manifest as it is, a non `Theme.AppCompat` value

---

The general rule is that if you want your code to support older versions of Android,  it should have the `AppCompat` theme and the java code should extend `AppCompatActivity`. If you have *an activity that doesn't need this support, such as you only care about the latest versions and features of Android, you can apply any theme to it but the java code must extend plain old `Activity`.

---

NOTE: When change from `AppCompatActivity` (or a subclass, `ActionBarActivity`), to `Activity`, must also change the various calls with "support" to the corresponding call *without* "support".  So, instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`, call `getFragmentManager`.

Comment: op is using appcompat in which case he should extend `ActionBarActivity` which is what is shown from his import statements from the comment below the quesiton.

Comment: So I have now changed my class to extend activity i.e. public class MainActivity extends Activity {. However, I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: He's trying to create a dialog themed activity which would not have an action bar. You can easily do this when using the AppCompat library but you cannot if your activity extends ActionBarActivity. If he changes the java code to extend from Activity he will have a dialog themed activity like his question is requesting. @ant2009 shouldn't you be changing com.ssd.register.Dialog_update to extend from Activity not MainActivity?

Comment: @Bobbake4, thanks you was correct. I have changed the code as you specified. And now it is working.

Comment: @Bobbake4 is there any other workaround without changing the parent  ActionBarActivity?

Comment: @shanavascet I'm not sure what you are asking here. Are you asking if there is a way to have an Activity inherit from ActionBarActivity without setting the theme to an AppCompat theme? If that is what you are asking no, you cannot extend ActionBarActivity without applying one of the AppCompat themes or extending one of those.

Comment: I'm getting this error, even when I have the Theme applied to my App thus: <application
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"> do I have to apply to all Activities individually as well?

Comment: @Andrew Nope shouldn't have to. The docs for the application theme say this will be the default theme for all activities (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#theme). If you want to create a new question with your manifest posted it might be easier to help diagnose. Link your question here.

Comment: Thanks @Bobbake4, that was my understanding also. The app compiles fine in IntelliJ and ant, and it's during my trying to mavenize it that I get the error. Probably something to do with the apklib dependency on the appcompat library....I'll need to investigate more myself first I think.

Comment: Omg @Bobbake4! You're the real MVP! A question, I just created the app and this error was on the code, is that a bug? Or I'm missing something

Comment: @Bursos If you're talking about when you create a new project in Android Studio I'm guessing that's a bug in the standard config.

Comment: @Bobbake4, Im having the same problem, and this solution is impossible to work for me. The thing is that I can't extend Activity, because I have a bunch of classes (whole project) that relay on ActionBarActivity. Is there any other solution to the problem? Thx

Comment: @5er If your Java is using ActionBarActivity the theme must extend Theme.AppCompat. There are a handful of built in themes that do extend Theme.AppCompat or you could extend it yourself and modify it. Without removing the ActionBarActivity parent you cannot get around using the Theme.AppCompat.

Comment: @Bobbake4 thanks, for respond. I afraid that removing ActionBarActivity is not an option. But I have to show the activity as a Dialog. Do you have any idea how to do that? 
If I found any workaround how to use Theme.AppCompat I will let you know.

Comment: In style <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> this solved my issue. :)

Comment: So why android studio generates MainActivity.java extending ActionBarActivity as default?

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me time as from exceptions it was not clear where the problem is. I tried to changed android:theme in androidmanifest.xml then also in styles.xml and also in both but it still threw exception from which it was not clear how to make it working :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21492572/150371 might be a good solution to overcome this as well

Comment: This answer is not correct if you want to implement Chromecast and Mediarouter. See tutorial for this. You then need AppCompatActivity which need its corresponding theme.

Comment: @carl This depends on what you are looking to do. If you look at the original posted question the user wanted to use theme `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog` for his activity. If you want to do this your activity cannot extend AppCompatActivity. If you are getting this error and do not have a requirement of using that theme then you can update the theme to solve the issue, but I do believe this answer is correct for the original posted question.

Comment: If you change from ActionBarActivity to Activity, operation like getSupportFragmentManager() will not be able. So it's not the right answer.

Comment: @Peter - when you change from `AppCompatActivity` (or a subclass, `ActionBarActivity`), to `Activity`, you must change the various calls with "support" to the corresponding call *without* "support".  So, instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`, call `getFragmentManager`.

Comment: Change ActionBarActivity is not a solution is a wrong workarround, because it affects the architecture of the Application. The solution is, as mentioned in other threads, to change contest for activity.this.

Comment: Mind that you have to import `android.app.AlertDialog` rather `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`

Answer (score 663):

All you need to do is add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to your application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: In the code, ant2009 has AppTheme set as the application them which extends from a descendant of Theme.AppCompat. That should work. I had the same problem after upgrading to 5.0 on my device and ended up setting @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light as the theme on my activity. Something not right here...

Comment: I have a theme added to each activity and application. Still does not work. There is still more to it.

Comment: This is not a valid answer for Android Studio, though it in some cases it will work as a quick fix when one is bypassing styles.xml files. In Android Studio, proper way to define theme is to define them in styles.xml files, and then the Android menifest file will merely refer to them, and select them based on which Android version you are running on your device. Usually it is set to android:theme="@style/AppTheme" and this AppTheme refers to  <style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> in styles.xml

Comment: This is basically deleting the reference to the Material theme. I don't think this helps getting anywhere. It's the same as saying NOT to use Material theme.

Comment: This didn't really work for me because my title bars disappeared when I used anything but holo...

Comment: This would not allow me to change the background color of the ActionBar. It would igrnore whatever value I used. Until I changed the activity class from ActionBarActivity to Activity as mentioned in the top rated answer.

Comment: Ran into this issue as well using the SnackBar.  This solved my issue.

Comment: @Martin if you are like me, you have forget to add the same style name in general file styles.xml than you put in (V21) styles.xml file (without the properties specific to V21). 
If you declare a style in V21 folder and your device have a version below. It can't find it so an exception is fired.

Answer (score 318):

Copying answer from @MarkKeen in the comments above as I had the same problem.

I had the error stated at the top of the post and happened after I added an alert dialog. I have all the relevant style information in the manifest. My problem was cured by changing a context reference in the alert builder - I changed:

```
new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

to:

```
new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

And no more problems.

Comment: It happened with me also. I was just trying and your answer really worked! What is the logic for it to get worked? I really didn't understood.

Comment: Or, if you are building your AlertDialog in a fragment, rather than directly in an Activity, use `getActivity()` rather than `this` as suggested above and the problem is fixed.
As for why, I can only surmise the older AlertDialog.Builder(xxx) code either wanted a different type passed in, or was simply less picky about what got passed in, while the current Builder() really, really wants an Activity. Since Google has chosen to hide (remove?) the documentation for the old code, presumably in an effort to encourage use of the v7.app version, I know of no way to tell for sure.

Comment: Did the opposite of what is suggested. And it worked :P. Thanks!

Comment: This solve the program for me, also you would use `getContext()` instead of `this` if you're inside an ArrayAdapter or similar adapter class.

Comment: In my onCreate I had been saving a member variable to hold context using getApplicationContext(). This answer led me to instead save context as "this", and crash went away. Thanks so much.

Comment: had the same issue, changed my style but still crashed. only worked after setting `this` to constructor

Comment: I knew completely this was the problem.. For those of you using builder in some listview(like me :P) `getApplicationContext()` is so tempting to use. Well this highlights with an error cannot be applied. Instead use **ActivityName.this**. Hope it helps for someone out there.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue, because I was calling this dialog from a different fragment, but the alert dialog needs to open from a floating action button which needs to be part of the main activity.

Comment: I think this is the real answer. I have observed AlertDialog don't work with baseContext from Activity, but it workS with " this " .

Comment: This is the genuine solution i ever meet. 

TIP: Please mention the difference in getApplicationContext() and this in this purpose.

Comment: Same thing happened to me ,once I changed the "getApplicationContext()" to "Activity.this" everything went smooth.

Comment: i'm here again in 2020. Your answer is my context doctor.

Comment: Thanks! I was using `AlertDialog` inside `Fragment`, all I had to do is give the builder `Activity` instead of `Context`.

Comment: very correct answer. should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 155):

If you are using the application context, like this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

change it to an activity context like this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Same if you're using LayoutInflater.from(<aplication context>), make sure you use the activity context or the provided LayoutInflater so that it inherits the right Theme.

Comment: Your solution helped me in my case. Can you explain what difference between getApplicationContext() and MainActivity.this?

Comment: refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext

Comment: you need an activity, not a context, to display dialogs

Comment: Then why on earth does `AlertDialog.Builder()` require a `Context`?

Answer (score 131):

min sdk is 10. `ActionBar` is available from api level 11. So for 10 you would be using `AppCompat` from the support library for which you need to use `Theme.AppCompat` or descendant of the same.

Use

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

Or if you dont want action bar at the top

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

More info @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Edit:

I might have misread op post.

Seems op wants a Dialog with a Activity Theme. So as already suggested by Bobbake4 extend `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`.

Also have a look @ Dialog Attributes in the link below

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/themes.xml/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that already actually. And I got the same problem. My styles file looks like this: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

Comment: @ant2009 you won't. Use a theme from the support library AppCompat for your activity

Comment: I not sure if I am adding this theme correct. But do you mean adding the following import statement? import android.support.v7.appcompat.*; However, I did try that and maybe I am wrong as I still ended up with the same exception.

Comment: @ant2009 you can have a custom dialog. But do you want to full screen dialog?

Comment: I didn't want to have it full screen. Just a dialog box. However, the problem is solved now. Bobbake4 got it right. Thanks for you effort anyway, you have given useful advice. However, I am still confused with all this support library and AppCompat.

Comment: @Raghunandan Hi. please help me in one issue related with map using KML file

Comment: Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886749/parsed-kml-file-doesnt-show-route-in-google-map-in-my-app

Answer (score 59):

I was experiencing this problem even though my Theme was an `AppCompat` Theme and my Activity was an `AppCompatActivity` (or `Activity`, as suggested on other's answers). So I cleaned, rebuild and rerun the project.

(**Build -> Clean Project ; Build -> Rebuild Project ; Run -> Run**)

*It may seem dumb, but now it **works great**!*

*Just hope it helps!*

Comment: Had exact same message after adding DialogFragment to the AppCompat activity. File, Invalidate Caches / Restart fixed that in a pinch.

Comment: I tried almost all answers in this thread. but only this seemingly "dumb" answer works. thank you!

Comment: When in doubt, assume Android Studio has silently corrupted your entire codebase and try rebuilding. This worked for me. Dear God, my hatred for Android knows no limit.

Answer (score 33):

This is what fixed it for me: instead of specifying the theme in manifest, I defined it in `onCreate` for each activity that extends `ActionBarActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.MyAppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);
...
}
```

Here `MyAppTheme` is a descendant of `Theme.AppCompat`, and is defined in xml. Note that the theme must be set before `super.onCreate` and `setContentView`.

Comment: Robolectric is throwing a NullPointerException at the setTheme line when trying to load the resource. Any idea why?

Comment: @RhysDavis Difficult to say without stack trace, but perhaps it wants setContentView first? In that case this fix will not work for you.

Answer (score 27):

go to your styles and put the parent

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat"
```

instead of

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Comment: Why can we do this with a standard activity. Did Android not put action bars on Standard Activities with ICS or Honecomb? Do we always have to use ActionBarActivity if we set our minimum target to SDK ICS?

Comment: how to see which theme we should use with the type or feature we are using because when we import we have all types of themes available

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me. :)

Answer (score 21):

Change the theme of the desired Activity. This works for me:

```
<activity
            android:name="HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Answer (score 19):

In my case i have no values-v21 file in my res directory. Then i created it and added in it following codes:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I was running my project on Oreo+ devices and only this worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

for me a solution, **after trying all solutions from here**, was to change

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.github.cythara.MainActivity"
        android:label="Main">
    </activity>
```

to include a theme:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.github.cythara.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:label="Main">
    </activity>
```

Comment: @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light works too if you want to keep the action bar.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35556478/3622415 and this is matter of how to use "Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)" In my case, adding google android material `implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")` solved problem. And `Theme.Material3.DayNight` was one of their theme - probably a descendent of `Theme.AppCompat`

Answer (score 18):

Just Do

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

Instead of

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: Working solution! 30 minutes to find out with this answer. Why I´m using new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())?

Comment: It will be helpful to explain what type is `this` expected to be.

Answer (score 16):

I had such crash on **Samsung** devices even though the activity did use *Theme.AppCompat*.
The root cause was related to weird optimizations on Samsung side:

```
- if one activity of your app has theme not inherited from Theme.AppCompat
- and it has also `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
- then all the activities that are launched from it will share the same Theme
```

My solution was just removing `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Comment: Just ran into this as well, I have not validated the fix and cannot reproduce the error.. but I am seeing this error in the wild on samsung devices only. most seem to be rooted as well, fwiw

Comment: I had the error stated at top of post and happened after I added an alert dialog.  I have all the relevant style information in the manifest.  My problem was cured by changing a context reference in the alert builder - I changed: new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()) to: new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this) and no more problems...

Comment: Do you have any more details or links to samsung about this optimisation? Do all activities then have to implement Theme.AppCompat or there can be activities with no theme?

Answer (score 14):

If you need to extend ActionBarActivity you need on your style.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

If you set as main theme of your application as android:Theme.Material.Light instead of **AppTheme.Base** then you’ll get an “IllegalStateException:You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity” error.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, but it solved when i put this on manifest: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name_test"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        ...    

    </application>
```

Comment: This is the right answer when updating from Activity to AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 11):

In my case such issue was appear when i tried to show Dialog.
The problem was in context, I've use **getBaseContext()** which theoretically should return Activity context, but appears its not, or it return context before any Theme applied.

So I just replaced **getBaseContexts()** with "**this**", and now it work as expected.

```
        Dialog.showAlert(this, title, message,....);
```

Comment: i was passing getApplicaitonContext(),but yours did the trick

Answer (score 10):

You have came to this because you want to apply Material Design in your theme style in previous sdk versions to 21. `ActionBarActivity` requires `AppTheme`so if you also want to prevent your own customization about your AppTheme, only you have to change in your styles.xml (previous to sdk 21) so this way, can inherit for an App Compat theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

for this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: Did that. Still have the problem. So there is more to it.

Answer (score 10):

I had an activity with theme `<android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">` used for showing dialog in my **appWidget** and i had same problem

i solved this error by changing activity code like below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog); //this line i added
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
}
```

Comment: This was a straightforward answer that worked for me without all the complexity and non-answer of the accepted one.

Answer (score 10):

In case the AndroidX `SplashScreen` library brought you here ...

This is because `Theme.SplashScreen` also has no `R.styleable.AppCompatTheme_windowActionBar`:

```
if (!a.hasValue(R.styleable.AppCompatTheme_windowActionBar)) {
    a.recycle();
    throw new IllegalStateException(
            "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.");
}
```

This requires switching the theme to the `postSplashScreenTheme`, before calling `super()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* When switching the theme to dark mode. */
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    /* When starting the Activity. */
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
    }
}
```

Then the `Theme.SplashScreen` from `AndroidManifest.xml` won't interfere.

---

Also quite related: When using `Theme.MaterialComponents`, there's a bridge theme contained, which works as substitute for `Theme.AppCompat`: `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge`.

This `Bridge` theme works despite `Theme.MaterialComponents` not inherits from `Theme.AppCompat`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge" />   
    <style name="AppTheme.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen" />    
</resources>
```

Comment: In Kotlin SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this)  changes to  installSplashScreen() as it is an extension function

Comment: Call installSplashScreen in the starting activity before calling super.onCreate(). https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate

Comment: For those who see this answer now, the reason that the "bridge themes" from material components (incl. `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge`) work is that they extend `Theme.AppCompat` indirectly (through several intermediate themes).

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are using an activity context while creating a new Alert Dialog and not an application or base context.

Answer (score 8):

for me was solution to use ContextThemeWrapper:

```
private FloatingActionButton getFAB() {
Context context = new android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.AppTheme);
FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(context);
return fab;}
```

from [Android - How to create FAB programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555834/android-how-to-create-fab-programmatically)

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem as well and what I did to fix it, AND still use the Holo theme was to take these steps:

first I replaced this import:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

with this one:

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

then changed my extension from:

```
public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity {//...
```

to this:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {//...
```

And also had to change this import:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

to this import:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

and then you can use your theme tag in the manifest at the activity level:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" />
```

and lastly, (unless you have other classes in your project that has to use v7 appCompat) you can either clean and rebuild your project or delete this entry in the gradle build file at the app level:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

if you have other classes in your project that has to use v7 appCompat then just clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 7):

This one worked for me:

```
<application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <activity
               android:name=".MainActivity"
               android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 7):

You have many solutions to that error.

1. You should use *Activity* or *FragmentActivity* instead of *ActionbarActivity* or *AppCompatActivity*
2. If you want use *ActionbarActivity* or *AppCompatActivity*, you should change in *styles.xml* *Theme.Holo.xxxx* to *Theme.AppCompat.Light* (if necessary add to *DarkActionbar*)

If you don't need advanced attributes about action bar or *AppCompat* you don't need to use *Actionbar* or *AppCompat*.

Answer (score 7):

In Android manifest just change theme of activity to AppTheme as follow code snippet

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</activity>
```

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this same problem. Because i was creating custom navigation drawer. But i forget to mention theme in my manifest like this

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

As soon i added the above the theme to my manifest it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

In my experiences the problem was the context where I showed my dialog.
Inside a button click I instantiate an AlertDialog in this way:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

But the context was not correct and caused the error. I've changed it using the application context in this way:

In declare section:

```
Context mContext;
```

in the onCreate method

```
mContext = this;
```

And finally in the code where I need the AlertDialog:

```
start_stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_stop);
start_stop.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
     {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (!is_running)
                    {
                        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                        builder.setMessage("MYTEXT")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    Task_Started = false;
                                    startTask();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("NO",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    }
            }
        }
```

This is the solution for me.

Comment: You're correct that you shouldn't be using an Application context the way you originally had it.  What you've done is use an Activity as the context instead.  This is not, however, an Application context or a subclass of it.  So it's not right to say you're using an Application context in a different way.

Answer (score 7):

I have faced same problem.

If you are providing context to any class or method then provide YourActivityName.this instead of getApplicationContext().

Do this

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```

Instead of

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your theme style parent to

```
 parent="Theme.AppCompat"
```

This worked for me ...

Answer (score 6):

Your Activity is extending **ActionBarActivity** which requires the **AppCompat.theme** to be applied.
Change from **ActionBarActivity** to **Activity** or **FragmentActivity**, it will solve the problem.

> If you use no Action bar then :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is when you want a AlertDialog in a Fragment

```
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            adb.setTitle("My alert Dialogue \n");
            adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                  //some code

            } });
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                 dialog.dismiss();

                } });
            adb.show();
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across this issue when using `SplashScreen Api`, this error is also thrown when `installSplashScreen()` is not called in the `MainActivity`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

Comment: Make sure installSplashScreen() is added.

Comment: I'll add to that installSplashScreen should be call before calling super()

Answer (score 5):

If someone sees this error while running Android 12 Splash screen then follow these simple steps

1. The app theme in `values/themes.xml` and `values-night/themes.xml`
   should have `Theme.AppCompat` as the parent theme.

   ```
   <style name="Theme.Ace" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   ```
2. Use this theme in `postSplashScreenTheme` for the splash screen theme

   ```
   <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
   <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/orange_900</item>
   <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_help_outline</item>
   <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">2000</item>
   <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Ace</item>
   ```
3. Remove any theme from the starting activity and use `Theme.App.Starting` as an application theme

   ```
   <application...
   android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Quick solution.

Change your base theme parent in styles.xml

Replace from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

Comment: does not help me, the exception still triggers

Answer (score 3):

My Activity with SectionsPagerAdapter and ViewPager & Fragment

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
...
...
     @Override
        public void onPostResume(){
            super.onPostResume();
            try {
               getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            }catch (NullPointerException ignored){
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me.

Design library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries, so don't use different version for appcompat and design library in gradle.

use

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

instead of

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

For me none of the above answers worked even after I had `Theme.AppCompat` as my base theme for the application. I was using `com.android.support:design:24.1.0` So I just changed the version to `24.1.1`. After the gradle sync, Its working again and the exception went away. Seems to me the issue was with some older versions of design support libraries.

Just putting this here in case other answers don't work for some people.

Comment: 24.1.1 did not help me when downgrading from 25.3.1, the exception still triggers

Comment: @EvgeniyPhilippov try upgrading it to `26.1.0`... I think this was fixed in this version currently using this. If it still doesn't work your issue may lye some where else.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i was inflating a `view` with `ApplicationContext`. When you use `ApplicationContext`, theme/style is not applied, so although there was `Theme.Appcompat` in my style, it was not applied and caused this exception. **More details**: [Theme/Style is not applied when inflater used with ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118251/theme-style-is-not-applied-when-inflater-used-with-applicationcontext)

Answer (score 3):

This really forced me to post my own answer.

Since I am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, and also replaced all `AlertDialog` instances with support compatibility imports and still faced problems below v21 (Lollipop).

I didn't like the idea of changing the theme which was proper.
So after 2 days, I finally gave some thought about the other libraries that are specifying `AppTheme` for their `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I found out that there is yet another one: [Paytm Checkout SDK](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/android-sdk/).

Thus, the following changes fixed the problem.

1. Renaming `AppTheme` using for my app to 'XYZAppTheme'
2. using `tools`:replace method in AndroidManifest of my project(app).

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
       android:name=".XYZ"
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_v2"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:largeHeap="true"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_v2_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/XYZAppTheme"
       tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme">

       <activity
           android:name=".xyz.SplashActivity"
           android:launchMode="singleTask"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

In your `app/build.gradle` add this dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03"
```

Update your `styles.xml` AppTheme's parent:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

When You're Using Kotlin, nothing solved my problem until I change the Builder parameter from 'applicationContext' to 'this'.

This  Does Not Work

```
val dialogDelete = AlertDialog.Builder(applicationContext)
            .setTitle("Confirmation")
            .setMessage("Delete this photo?")
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no){ it, which ->
                it.dismiss()
            }
dialogDelete.show()
```

Following Code Works

```
val dialogDelete = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Confirmation")
            .setMessage("Delete this photo?")
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no){ it, which ->
                it.dismiss()
            }
dialogDelete.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are struggling with the Recyclerview Adapter class then use

```
view.getRootView().getContext()
```

instead of

```
getApplicationContext() or activity.this
```

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: I had intended this as an answer, but further testing reveals it still fails when built using maven from the command line, so I've had to edit it to be a problem! :-(

In my case when I got this error I was already using a AppCompat Theme and the error didn't make much sense.

I was in the process of mavenizing my android build. I had already dependencies on the apklib and jar versions of app compat, thus:

```
    <!-- See https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
            <version>${compatibility.version}</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v7</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Now, when I import the maven project and build and run from IntelliJ it's fine.

But when I build and deploy and run from the command line with maven I still get this exception.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio:
Add support library to the gradle file and sync.
Edit `build.gradle(Module:app)` to have dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

My support Library version is `23.1.1`; use your support library version as applicable.

Answer (score 2):

For me issue resolved by changing the inheritance from AppCompatActivity to Activity in my customDialog class. No changes required in manifest for Theme.Dialog.

Answer (score 2):

If using getApplicationContext() as the parameter while inflating the layout, you can try to use getBaseContext() instead. e.g.

```
    View.inflate(getBaseContext(),
            getLayoutId() == 0 ? R.layout.page_default : getLayoutId(),
            null);
```

Comment: It might be good to save `getLayoutId()` in a variable rather than repeating the call twice.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are passing the right context to your `Dialog`. This happened to me and then I realized I was initiating `AlertDialog.Builder` with `applicationContext` instead of `Activity` context.

Answer (score 2):

So I was using an activity which was extending from AppCompatActivity. I changed this to FragmentActivity and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Change Theme from highlighted tab in picture.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using a style called "FullScreenTheme", and although it seemed to be correctly defined (it was a descendant of `Theme.AppCompat`) it was not working.

I finally realized that I was using an AAR library that internally also had defined a style called "FullScreenTheme" and *it was not* descendant of `Theme.AppCompat`. The clashing of the names was causing the problem.

Fix it by renaming my own style name so now Android is using the correct style.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had `AppTheme` in `AndroidManifest` set correctly to a style that inherited from `Theme.AppCompat`. However, the individual activities had style settings in `AndroidManifest` that were overriding that.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to clean the project after VCS Local History restore

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add this as import => import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog

I am posting this being the smallest ever solution to the problem.
I just changed the instantiation of

`new AlertDialog.Builder(mContex)`

to

`new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.PreferenceDialogLight)`

Where `<style name="PreferenceDialogLight" parent="Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **VCS** in your project (**GIT**, for instance), try to:

1. **Delete your local project files;**
2. **Re-import from remote.**

Problem solved!

*In my case, I deleted a file that contained erros, but somehow Studio was still detecting the file and therefore preventing it from building.*

***Hope it helps!***

Answer (score 1):

Change Manifest file from

**@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light** //whichever is mentioned for application

to

**@android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"**

This got me worked..hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error because my activity was extending AppCompatActivity. The solution for my case was to change the base class which the activity was extending from AppCompatActivity to ComponentActivity.

Answer (score 1):

IN MaterialAlertDialogBuilder use "this" without "applicationContext"

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're having this issue and you're instantiating a Material 3 dialog view programmatically:

Make sure not to use *getApplicationContext()* when requiring a Context instance, but instead use this or *YourActivity.this*

For example.. Instead of this

```
  new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getApplicationContext())
```

Use

```
 new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(WHatEverActivityYouHostTheDialog.this)
```

Make sure your Activity is extended from AppCompactActivity

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Android SDK didn't seem to be able to find the styles definition. Everything was wired correctly and doing a simple project clean fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

just make that

> getApplicationContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.Theme_Mc,
>   true);

and In your values/styles.xml 
add this

```
 <style  name="Theme.Mc" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
         <!-- ADD Your Styles  -->


     </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all of this, about changing a lot of this in your app.. just do it simple as this video does.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bsm-BlXo2SI

I already use it so... it's a 100 percent effective.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck several hours at this problem. The problem was that I implemented my own `.jar` dependency that didn't uses the `Theme.AppCompat` style in it's `themes.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml`. Even after I changed and rebuild my dependency it didn't work. After a bit of research I found out that I should use an `.aar (Android Archive)` library as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library). After changing my dependency module to an Android Library I could build and implement it without errors. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to add this free explorer module (**NoNonsense - FilePicker**) to my current App, I got this Exception:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity**

This code to add for the module to work was in a styles.xml file in a previous App, and it worked fine:

```
<!-- You can also inherit from NNF_BaseTheme.Light -->
<style name="FilePickerTheme" parent="NNF_BaseTheme">
    <!-- Set these to match your theme -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- Setting a divider is entirely optional -->
    <item name="nnf_list_item_divider">?android:attr/listDivider</item>

    <!-- Need to set this also to style create folder dialog -->
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/FilePickerAlertDialogTheme</item>

    <!-- If you want to set a specific toolbar theme, do it here -->
    <!-- <item name="nnf_toolbarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item> -->
</style>

<style name="FilePickerAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

But this doesn't work in a recent App. The solution was simple, I simply moved the code to the themes.xml file (and deleted it from the styles.xml file).
For some reason, there's this subtle change in the modern version. Kind of obvious, but if something was working, then it normally is the correct way...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably going to be an idiosyncratic answer, but the off-chance it helps someone else, say you're using a `splash.xml` for a splash screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.StartScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/ic_launcher_background</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Assignment4</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/splash_screen_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**android:statusBarColor will cause this error.** I copy-pasted this from my previous assignment and my next assignment did not use a status bar.

Answer (score -1):

For my Xamarin Android project (in MainActivity.cs), I changed…

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

…and the error went away. I realise that isn't a solution for everyone but it might give a clue to the underlying problem.

Comment: For non-Xamarin.Forms just use the regular Activity class instead of AppCompatActivity that the tutorials tell you to use.

Answer (score -2):

In case anybody still wondering about this issue.

try this :

```
new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

Comment: That's not related to the question.

Comment: To [reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11985108): if the answer is bad, even if it's not relevant to the question, but is an attempt to answer the question (like this appears to be), don't recommend deletion: downvote! See [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007). This is an answer. You may not agree with it, but it is an attempt to answer the question.