# Remove target _blank for all hyper links in WebView

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webview

Err this is not related to android and this question is about to be marked as a duplicate of android related question. ???

I need to remove `target=_blank` from all hyper links so that all links will be opened in the same webview.
When i searched for similar Q&As most of them suggested injecting a javascript which would convert all `target=_blanks` to `_self`. I am testing this in a browser window first, and the script indeed converts all hyperlinks but it has no effect, it still continues to open in a new window. How can I force it to open in same window/webview ?

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].target == "_blank")
        a[i].target = "_self";
```

Comment: Have you checked if the loop ever runs? Maybe there are no `a` tags at the time you're executing your script.

Comment: Make sure that you place this script after all the DOM elements are loaded.

Comment: @Teemu I Am testing this script in a Browser(Chrome), and am injecting this through console. And I can verify that target has been changed through developer inspector tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link should be open in same web view in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android)

Comment: @MatthewRiches Answers over there are not generic and cannot be implemented in osx.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your JavaScript is correct. I suspect you've created test html page to check it. In this case, you need to place script in the end of page, otherwise it will not affect links:

```
<body>
<!-- This will work -->
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">google.com</a>
<script>
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        if (a[i].target == "_blank")
            a[i].target = "_self";
</script>
<!-- This link will not be modified -->
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">google.com</a>
</body>
```

You need to inject this script in your `WebView`. Use following code in your `WebFrameLoadDelegate`:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSString *script = @"var a = document.getElementsByTagName(\"a\");\n" \
                        "for (i=0; i<a.length; i++) {\n" \
                        "    if (a[i].target == \"_blank\") {\n" \
                        "        a[i].target = \"_self\";\n" \
                        "    }\n" \
                        "};";
    [frame.javaScriptContext evaluateScript:script];
}
```

Note that this script should be performed for each frame separately.

Hope it helps.