# android webview unset default browser

Tags: android, webview

I use the following to show a webpage in a webview

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setClickable(true);
    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
    }
```

It works perfect and even has pinch and zoom however When i click to go to another webpage via a link it opens it in the default browser instead of the webview

How to i achieve this. I have read many articles on this but cant understand where i need to insert the commands

Any help appreciated

Mark

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7309017

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much for the link above the following works perfect

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://someurl.com");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
    viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
    return false;
}
});
```