# Cordova - Open link inside app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, webview

I'm working on android application with `cordova` and `angular`.
I try to open external link inside the webview, but it's always opens in chrome...

I tried to use:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(link, {openExternal:false})
```

and also:

```
window.open(link, '_self', 'location=yes')
```

What i'm missing?

Thank you :)

Comment: If you open an external link inside your app you will break everything and you won't be able to go back to your app, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

InAppBroser should be you want.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

```
// !! Assumes filePath is a valid path on the device

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);
```

Comment: InAppBrowser not good for me because I need to allow the user to download from the external link and InAppBrowser didn't support downloading...

Comment: webview not support download,need native implement; you can use http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

Comment: But how can I use it? I want to allow the user to download from a website that not belong to me :(

Comment: @Yehuda, you have another question where you got an answer about how to make inAppBrowser plugin download files.

Answer (score 1):

You should try :

```
window.open(myURL, '_blank'); => OPEN IN INAPPBROWSER
```

OR

```
window.open(myURL, '_system');  => OPEN IN SYSTEM BROWSER
```

ADVICE : you should try to encode your URL : `myURL = encodeURI(urlStr);`

Comment: InAppBrowser is not good for me.. it's not support file downloading to the device...

Answer (score 1):

you can try use WebViewClient:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
            viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Credit goes to this post: [Link should be open in same web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android)

Comment: Where should i put it in cordova?

Comment: sorry, this example is for webview in Android. I'll look how to do this in cordova.