# How Can I Continue Internet Link Action With My App?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview. My question is, when user clicks to a link in webview, how to continue with my app?

When user clicks to a link, this dialog box appearing:

[image: continue with dialogbox]

How can I avoid this dialogbox and continue with my app?

WebView Code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Edit (MYActivity İn Test project)

```
package com.mycompany.myapp5;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.webkit.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
WebView view;
String url="http://google.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android) is exactly what you need.

The idea is to set a WebViewClient to your WebView and override shouldOverrideUrlLoading method like below:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps you!

---

Here is the complete code from a test project that is running.

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in the Activity:

```
WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        String url="http://www.google.com";
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

This works fine in a 4.4 device. Please try this and let me know if you still have the issue.

Comment: Aren't you getting an exception while doing this? When you say it does not work, do you mean the Exception? Or do you mean the urls are still showing the popup?

Comment: Oops Sorry you are right. I created a new project and tested your code. App force stopping. Code in first post

Comment: Can you explain the downvote please? I have updated the answer with a working copy of the code. It runs fine.

Comment: I didnt. you can believe me. I'll test tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: I believe you :) Perhaps who down voted could reply.

Comment: Do you see anything in logcat?