# Open a link on WebView

Tags: java, android, html, url, android-webview

I am using WebView on my application.
the WebView contains a web site with link.
When I am clicking on the link, it is open the link on the application(By webView).
How can I open the link with the browser?
Thank you!

Comment: you can find it here Captain - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7309017/6525469

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```

or if you need to override Webview link click use this

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
```

This should do the trick