# Open and encrypted url using webview

Tags: android, android-webview

How do I can open this URL using webview in Android?

http://newinvest.erokda.in/downloadglobalfile.php?filename=811536217871_mandate-MTIwNzkw-NzE3OQ==-.pdf&path=1&userId=MTIwNzkw&action=globalfiledownload&aData=OTYxOTc5NzA4OXx5dGVzdGlkMDFAZ21haWwuY29t

Comment: add code here that you are using already to load url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android open URL in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759449/android-open-url-in-webview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML WebView element in layout.

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

And then just do the following.

```
// ......
final String url = "<your link text>"
// ......
final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.loadUrl(url );
// ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other URL, but encode with UTF-8 to retain special characters.

```
URLEncoder.encode(URL, "utf-8");
```